# What to do in case of an MDM solution admin account takeover?

Tags: threat-mitigation, privileged-account

My company recently switched to an MDM solution to manage our Apple computers fleet. This is all good and well to maintain up-to-date software, and make handle lost/stolen laptop issues.

But I can help but wonder about how to mitigate a possible issue with the MDM solution (either with one of the admin accounts or the solution provider itself).

I know it's really a worst-case scenario here since we picked a (we think) correct MDM solution and are following best practices to protect the admin accounts, but I believe for security we have to prepare for the worst.

I think that getting the laptops locked of wiped is not really an issue, what worries me the most is the possibility for an attacker to use the MDM to install on one or more computers things like data stealer, keyloggers or to use that computer to attack more sensitive devices.

How can one alleviate this risk of an MDM takeover and/or detect it asap?